# Azure DevOps 2020 missing folder in source control

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

we have a Azure DevOps 2020 on premises (not a cloud version). We have a project lets call it MacGyver.
In web interface there is missing folder (GUIV2) (image 3).
But files can be seen, if I access them from Changeset email (image 1).
In visual studio the folder exists with lock symbol on each file (image 2).
If I download the solution as a zip file, the folder exists in the zip file.

I did restart the VM. I have checked that there is now second workspace with different mapping. Other team members also have the same issue. Also, I am administrator on Azure DevOps server.

[image: Changeset email]

[image: Visual studio]

[image: Missing folder]

Comment: Have you reviewed your TFVC RBAC?

Comment: @DanielMann all screens are taken with the same user.